# pulling a value from a spark dataframe without it rounding the value

Tags: pandas, pyspark, cluster-analysis, rounding

I'm attempting to verify something in my spark dataset.  I'm taking a set of columns I'm using inside a clustering algorithms, producing a feature column, then normalizing the data.  Spark does all this just fine.  However, I noticed that when I convert the results of the filtering of my data into a pandas dataframe, spark's *toPandas*, *head*, and *first* functions all round the values.  This means they're hard to plot and useless to any functions outside of spark.  Is there a way to shut this off?

So I do the following:

```
    assembler_t = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['unixTime','value_hrf','value_raw'],           
    outputCol="features",handleInvalid="keep")
    result_t = assembler_t.transform(result)
    normalizer_t=Normalizer(inputCol='features', outputCol='normalized_features')
    result_t=normalizer_t.transform(result_t)
```

The result of `result_t.select('normalized_features').show()` is a table that looks like this:

```
    | normalized_features|
    |--------------------|
    |[0.99999999999980...|
    |[0.99999999999980...|
    |[0.99999999999980...|
    |[0.99999999999979...|
```

You see the first problem.  the values are so close together, large amounts of decimals are required.  Also, there's three values per row and only one is being shown.  So I figured I'd look at just one: `result_t.first()['normalized_features']`

Unfortunately, this produces the following:
`DenseVector([1.0, -0.0, -0.0])`

The same thing happens if I use the *head* or *toPandas* functions.  All I'm trying to figure out is if the values produced are unique and if I can get them output with their full decimal places.  The built-in KMeans algorithm seems to produce an output that indicates they're unique, but I want to be sure.  Also, since I'm using algorithms that don't exist in spark as well, I need to output the pre-run filtered data into a pandas DF to use it.  When I do this, the normalized data is useless, so I have to use something like a min-max scalar to get something similar.  However, I'm worried this will introduce bias in the data since normalization from algorithm to algorithm isn't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the full pandas dataframe without any column truncation using the following function.

```
def print_pandas(dataframe_given):
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None,'display.max_columns', None, 'expand_frame_repr', False, 'display.max_colwidth', None):
        print("Given dataframe name")
        print(dataframe_given)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This let's me see the full values so at least I know they're not being rounded.